# see incoming request from Java app in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using a Java based image uploader and having problems, seems my controller action is not being hit if I upload multiple files.  I can't use fiddler or FireBug because they don't pickup the Java apps request to the server.  I need to see what is being requested in debug mode so I can fix my Route - I am assuming this is my problem.

How can I hook into this and see what the request is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use a web debugging proxy (like Fiddler) if your Java based image uploader supports a proxy. Other than that you can use a packet sniffer like Wireshark or break your debug session at a point with a `HttpContext`, e.g. in `Global.asax` at `BeginRequest`.